# Is it possible to configure a Linux server to use more than one LDAP target?

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, authentication

We have an environment that we are tasked with managing while also giving access to projects that run the applications on the servers. Some of those projects have stood up LDAP for authenticating project users. Without getting into the discussion of why we didn't do it right in the first place we would now like to stand up our own LDAP to manage our users while not stepping on the existing LDAP configurations stood up by each project. Basically, our LDAP would be entirely separated from the project LDAP.

Is it possible to configure Linux (RHEL) to authenticate against more than one LDAP server? I'm thinking in terms of cascading authentication options: Check LDAP 1 for an account; If no account exists check LDAP 2; If no account exists check locally.

It seems like this would be possible, but having never configured LDAP I have no knowledge of whether it actually is a configurable methodology.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

- `sssd` with multiple domains
- `sssd` with single domain and [`slapd-meta(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd-meta)
- `nss-ldap` and `pam_ldap` with `slapd-meta`